# Windows 7 integration with Delphi

Tags: delphi, windows-7, vcl

I need components to integrate my app to Windows 7. I'm talking about the taskbar's ability to have progressbar, buttons, text and so on.

What is the best you know?

Comment: Can't you do it with the COM interfaces yourself? It doesn't sound particularly hard.

Answer (score 5):

I don't know about components, but I've seen a few blog posts that explain how to implement this yourself.  Check out http://www.drbob42.com/examines/examinC5.htm and http://alex.ciobanu.org/?p=215, for example.

Answer (score 3):

[Daniel Wischnewski](http://www.gumpi.com/Blog/) is developing some [Windows 7 components](http://www.gumpi.com/Blog/CategoryView,category,Windows%2B7.aspx) for Delphi.

[This video](http://www.gumpi.com/Blog/2009/09/27/DelphiControlsForWindows7StateUpdate.aspx) on his blog, demonstrates some of the features.

Comment: very buggy! Actually the progressbar on the preview window on the taskbar is needed, not on the actual block on the taskbar, but on the preview window.

Answer (score 3):

There's a package of Windows 7 components, free with source, at [delphi.fsprolabs.com](http://delphi.fsprolabs.com). The best I can say is that the components perform as expected, when you work out how to use them: the implementation is not very elegant and I found it hard to get started with them. Mason Wheeler's link to DrBob's post will get you to about the same point but you will gain useful knowledge along the way.

Answer (score 2):

There is also a project hosted on goolge code from [The unknownones](http://code.google.com/p/theunknownones/) with a component set
called [TaskbarListComponents](http://code.google.com/p/theunknownones/wiki/TaskbarListComponents).

It looks to be a very nice and a complete implementation.

You can see them in action here.

http://www.vimeo.com/14291783  TTaskbarListThumbButtons and TTaskbarListOverlayIcon

http://www.vimeo.com/14354328 TTaskbarListProgress

http://www.vimeo.com/14356627 TTaskbarlistFormTab and TTaskbarlistControlTab